# ReadFile named pipe after client closed other end

Tags: winapi, networking, named-pipes

I have multithreaded app working quite well, except the following scenario:
Initially I read from pipe 16 bytes, then depending on the header I read the rest.

The problem is that sometimes client writes a message (say 300 bytes long) and then close connection.

My server receives first 16 bytes, then decide to get the rest  284 bytes, but ReadFile returns error 233 (No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

So, where are those 284 bytes go ? I suppose they should be in a pipe buffer or something.

Pipe created as usually like in all examples over the net:

```
 HANDLE h= CreateNamePipe(
    name,                  // pipe name
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |        // read/write access
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,       // overlapped mode
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |         // message-type pipe
    PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |     // message read mode
    PIPE_WAIT,                  // blocking mode
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,   // unlimited instances
    100000,                   // output buffer size
    100000,                   // input buffer size
    0,               // client time-out
    lpSecurityAttributes);                     // default security attributes
```

Comment: OK, and check your client to see that it is calling `FlushFileBuffers()` before disconnecting the pipe. (which it should be doing with `DisconnectNamedPipe()` before `CloseHandle()`).

Comment: WhozCraig, thank you for your comment. But unfortunately I can't modify the client. Its 3rd party program.

Answer (score 0):

As WhozCraig noticed, client does not do FlushFileBuffers before DisconnectNamePIpe. Unfortunately.